# Determining the round of a match in a knock out tournament

Tags: combinatorics

I have a knock-out tournament with $n$ players. The players are $P1$, $P2$, ... $Pn$.

In a tournament with 8 players there are the matches $M1$ (between $P1$ and $P2$), to $M4$ (between $P7$ and $P8$) in round 1. In round 2 the matches are $M5$ and $M6$ and in round 3 is the match $M7$.

Now I need a formula to calculate the round number for a given $M$. I think this should be pretty simple, but I have no idea what to look for.

Comment: Are you sure that there are $2^n$ players? If so, you cannot enumerate them from $P_1$ to $P_n$ for an integer number of players because $2^n=n$ does not have a real solution. (A solution to 2^n=n can be obtained with the analytic continuation of the product log-function. However this solution would not be a real number). My guess is that it's $n$ players and not $2^n$ players?

Comment: @YukiJ Yes, you are right, I changed that. I wanted to make clear that only powers of 2 are possible.

Comment: I understand how to calculate the number of matches in each round, but I would like to get _which_ round we are in when I only know $n$ and the match number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the number of players is $n$ and not $2^n$: In round 1 there are $n/2$ matches. In round 2 there are $n/4$ matches. In round $k$ there are $\frac{n}{2^k}$ matches. There are a total of $\log_2(n)$ rounds. The total number of matches is thus $$\sum_{i=1}^{\log_2(n)} \frac{n}{2^i}=n-1.$$

If you want to find out in which round match $j$, i.e. $M_j$, has taken place, you are looking for the minimal round $k$ ($k$ integer) such that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{n}{2^i} \geq j.$$

In an optimization context one might write that the round number $R(j$) of match $j$ is given by

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
R(j)=& {\text{minimize}}
& & k \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{n}{2^i}\geq j,\\
&& &k \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Luckily, we don't have to use integer-programming methods to solve the problem. The number of matches up to round $k$ is given by  $$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{n}{2^i} = n-2^{-k}n.$$ We thus need to solve $$j=n-2^{-k}n$$ for $k$. Since the $k$ obtained this way needs not to be an integer, we have to round it to the next higher integer. Thus, $R(j)=\lceil k \rceil$ with $k$ satisfying $j=n-2^{-k}n$.Solving the equation for $k$ yields $k=\frac{\log(\frac{n}{n-j})}{\log 2}$. This value then needs to be rounded to the next highest integer.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, $j$ is the match number, $n$ is the number of players and $k$ is the round I am looking for, right? If so, how can I solve the formula for $k$?

Comment: You are right with the variables. I added the precise calculation of $k$ in the answer. It is $k=\frac{\log(\frac{n}{n-j})}{\log 2}.$ Then round $k$ to the next highest integer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for your time!